# file/rok2YK_D6Oc.mp3: No such file or directory Error

Tags: python, discord

I solved yesterday's problem, but the song still didn't play, so I'm writing again

Do you have any suggestions for handling this Error?

Did I specify the path of the file weirdly?

```
import youtube_dl

import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('켜짐')

    print(client.user.id)

    print('--------------------------')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('핑크야 들어와'):
        await message.author.voice.channel.connect()

        await message.channel.send('빠밤')

    if message.content.startswith('핑크야 나가'):

        for vc in client.voice_clients:

            if vc.guild == message.guild:
                voice = vc

        await voice.disconnect()

        await message.channel.send('힝...')

    if message.content.startswith('핑크야 재생'):

        for vc in client.voice_clients:

            if vc.guild == message.guild:
                voice = vc

        url = message.content.split(" ")[1]

        option = {

            'outtmpl': "file/" + url.split('=')[1] + ".mp3"

        }

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(option) as ydl:

            ydl.download([url])

            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

            title = info["title"]

        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("file/" + url.split('=')[1] + ".mp3"))

        await message.channel.send(title + "재생할게!")


client.run("")
```

This is the error code.

What do I need to do to make me find the directory?

I would really appreciate it if you could let me know the site I can refer to

```
file/rok2YK_D6Oc.mp3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: is the `file` directory in the same directory from which you are running your code?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to specify the file path